# Quadratic programming with linear equality constraints - dual problem conditions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have implemented an interior-point method algorithm tailored to a given class of problems (with following parameters: $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, g \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$):
\begin{eqnarray}
PQP: \quad  &\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\mathrm{min}}&\; \frac{1}{2} x^{T} H x + g^{T}x \\
&\mathrm{subject\;to}&\; Ax = b, \\
&&\; x \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray}
If I understand correctly, the Lagrangian function is as follows:
\begin{equation}
L(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{2} x^{T} H x + g^{T}x + y^{T} (b - Ax) - z^{T}x = b^{T} y - \frac{1}{2} x^{T} H x + x^{T} \left( Hx + g - A^{T} y - z \right),
\end{equation}
what would mean that a dual problem to the given one is constructed like that:
\begin{eqnarray}
DQP: \quad  &\underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\mathrm{max}}&\; b^{T} y - \frac{1}{2} x^{T} H x \\
&\mathrm{subject\;to}&\; Hx + g - A^{T} y - z = 0, \\
&&\; z \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray}
(for brevity, I left $x$ in the objective function, but it can be easily derived from condition).

While checking for stopping condition, I validate if both primal and dual constraints are met:

- primary: $b - Ax = 0$
- dual: $Hx + g - A^{T} y - z = 0$

Since I have used Matlab environment, I compared results with `quadprog` function. What's bothering me is that solution doesn't meet dual problem constraints (primary is fine), neither for my implementation nor for `quadprog`.

It got me thinking that I might have wrongly defined a dual problem or that there is a weak duality gap, but I cannot find any reasonable source to validate that suspicions in the Internet (most of them refer only to inequality cases).

Comment: "for brevity, I left x in the objective function, but it can be easily derived from condition)" I don't understand this. $x$ should not appear in the dual problem.

Comment: From $Hx+g−ATy−z=0$ we can get $x = H^{-1} (A^{T}y + z - g)$, and later (assuming that $H$ is symmetric and positive definite):
$-\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Hx = -\frac{1}{2}(A^{T}y + z - g)^{T} (H^{-1})^{T} H H^{-1} (A^{T}y + z - g) = -\frac{1}{2}(A^{T}y + z - g)^{T} H^{-1} (A^{T}y + z - g)$ .

Comment: @mattrym your recent comment shows you assume $H$ is a positive-definite matrix. If it's not, you might encounter problems. Moreover, if $H$ is not at least PSD, then interior-point method will fail on the problem.